# Groovy: unexpected token

Tags: groovy

```
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
    data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d});
    data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
```

How do I represent this in Grails? Grails complains on this statements saying: Groovy: unexpected token: data @ line 230, column 3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Lists are indicated by square brackets. But if you need an *actual* array, you must make one:

```
data.put("1", ["Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"] as Object[])
```

Depending on what you *actually* need, this might be nicer:

```
data = [
  "1": [ "Emp No.", "Name", "Salary" ],
  "2": [ 1d, "John", 1500000d ],
  "3": [ 2d, "Sam", 800000d ]
]
println data

> [1:[Emp No., Name, Salary], 2:[1.0, John, 1500000.0], 3:[2.0, Sam, 800000.0]]
```

I'd also recommend spending even a small amount of time checking out the Groovy language docs, or just looking around for a brief tutorial so you know the basics of Groovy syntax.

Comment: escpecially http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_differences_with_java